# Entity Framework - parent child table update in single transation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on application where I have a parent child relation between `User` and `Orders` tables. Below are the table structures:

**User:**

```
Column  | DataType  | Constraint
--------|-----------|-------------
UserId  | int       | Primary key
Username| varchar   |
Email   | varchar   |
IsActive| bit       |
```

**Order:**

```
Column  | DataType  | Constraint
--------|-----------|----------
OrderId | int       | Primary key
UserId  | int       | Foreign key to User.UserId
Type    | smallint  |
Quantity| smallint  |
```

As per the functionality I have to update User and his orders in one go where orders can be dynamically added, removed or updated.

I am using Entity Framework 6.0 and I cannot find any best solution to update parent table (`user`) and child table (`order`) in single transaction.

Could any one explain the best approach to achieve such functionality ?

Below is the code I am using:

Please take a note that I am using AutoMapper to map Object to Entity

```
public bool ManageUser(UserModel userDetails, string deletedOrders)
{
    var isSuccess = false;
    try
    {
        using (var entity = new UserEntity())
        {
            if (userDetails.UserId == 0)
            {
                entity.Users.Add(Mapper.Map<User>(userDetails));
            }
            else
            {
                var userToEdit = Mapper.Map<User>(userDetails);

                foreach (var item in userToEdit.Orders)
                {
                    if (item.OrderId == 0)
                    {
                        entity.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entity.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }

                /*** 
                * How to Write a code here to remove orders using deletedOrders parameter
                * Note: deletedOrders contains comma separated Id of the orders which needs to be removed. e.g. "1,5,6" 
                ****/

                entity.Entry(userToEdit).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }

            entity.SaveChanges();
            isSuccess = true;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

**Note:** This is just a simple code. But what if I will have multiple child tables like `Order` ? If I would follow the same practice than code will become complex and hard to handle. So looking for best approach for such scenarios.

Comment: Show us the code you have for now !

Comment: @marc_s: I have added a code. Please see multiline comments which confuses me.

Comment: When calling SaveChanges all changes inside the context are written to the db within a single transaction. So you are done.

Comment: @SirRufo: You are right. But I want to perform delete operation for deleted orders as well. which I cannot understand.

Comment: Find the order and then remove it from the DbSet or set the state of that entity to Deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to make a trip to database for entities which should be deleted then.

1. If `userDetails.Orders` includes orders which should be deleted, you change their states inf your `foreach (var item in userToEdit.Orders)` cycle to `System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted`.
2. If not, you simply create ones with suitable id's, attach them and then change their `EntityState` to `Deleted` as well:

   ```
   var ordersToDelete = deletedOrders.Split(new[] {','},
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => new Order 
       { 
           Id = int.Parse(x.Trim())
       })
       .ToList();

   ordersToDelete.ForEach(o => 
       entity.Entry(x).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);
   ```

Comment: Alternative way to #1: inf foreach cycle you check if `orderId` belongs to `deletedOrders` and then delete it from `userToEdit.Orders`. But in this case change `foreach` to `for` loop.

Comment: But still, do you suggest anything for more child tables and reduce the complexity ?

Comment: Will you pass id's to delete for each child type as a separate method's parameter? Maybe generics + objects instantiation action in that case?